# Safari (Mac OS X Lion) returns wrong epochtime value to position.timestamp call

Tags: javascript, safari, timestamp

I am creating a website that uses W3C Geolocation API and position.timestamp for timestamp. I have tested it on Safari 5.1.6 (Mac OS X Lion) and iPhone (5.x). iPhone default browser returns correct value for timestamp, while Safari does not. Has anyone experience similar issue? Is there a bug in Safari?

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vRRdE/2/

Running the test above (thanks Tyilo) I get `360419807893` (wrong one using `position.timestamp`) and `1338727007910` (correct one using `Date().getTime()`) using Safari on Mac OS X.

Comment: Also I have this problem too.

Comment: Thank you Tyilo for confirming the issue.

Comment: Well, what values are you getting exactly?

Comment: Running the test above (thanks Tyilo) I get 360419807893 (wrong one using position.timestamp) and 1338727007910 (correct one using Date().getTime()) using Safari on Mac OS X.

Comment: On iPad I get 1338727150066 using position.timestamp and 1338727150239 using Date().getTime() - almost identical.

Comment: Weird, +1. Are you sure you have not conducted any time-travel experiments recently? Are all time machines in your house turned off? Remember, just putting them into sleep mode will not turn them off completely

Comment: :-) Pekka, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and Safari on OS X. Chrome's looking fine. It's not working for me at all in Safari though. (Where does Safari have its JS console?)

Comment: You need to enable Develop menu first in Preferences -> Advanced

Comment: Thanks. Strange, it's not doing anything for me in Safari even though I allowed the position check. No errors in the console, the `getCurrentPosition()` just is never coming back. I think it may be trying to get the location, but fails

Comment: Pekka, please try error call back function to check if it fails.

Comment: It says position unavailable. That's a local issue then, I guess it can't get any location info from my WLAN. Chrome probably uses other info (like IP address, or info from my Google profile) to find out the position... nothing to do with your problem though, I'm interested to see what caused this.

Comment: I have found this relevant info: http://openradar.appspot.com/9246279

Comment: Seems indeed to be relevant. Open since April 2011? Ugh.

Comment: I have filled out Apple's Safari Bug Report.

Comment: Awesome, still not fixed.  Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that desktop Safari uses January 1, 2001 as the default epoch so the best approach here is probably just using Date().getTime();

Comment: thanks, I have decided using this function call instead for now

Comment: Better use Date.now(). You don't really need to create a new Date object.